# Activity間の画面推移の途中でアプリが停止してしまう

Tags: android, java

カメラ機能が付いたActivity(TakePictureActivity)から写真のアップロードのActivity(Main5Activity)へと画面推移がしたいのですが、実機で実行するとアプリが停止してしまいます。コードは以下のようになっております。どなたか教えてくださると大変助かります。

```
public class TakePictureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Uri _imageUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_picture);


    Button tosend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.to_send);
    tosend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(TakePictureActivity.this,Main5Activity.class);

            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: エラーログはどうなっていますか？

Comment: 特にエラーが見つからないので困っています

Comment: build のときも何も言われないのですが、アプリが落ちてしまうのです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity遷移の途中で実行時エラーということですので、症状を聞いた限りですと、AndroidManifest.xmlにMain5Activity.classの記載が抜けているように思えます。
このケースではbuildは通りますがActivityの遷移部分で落ちます。（Logcatにエラー内容が表示されるのですが、ビルド時のエラーチェックのようにエラーがピンポイントで表示されるようなことは無く、大量に流れていっているエラーログの中に混ざっているので注意して見ないと見落とす可能性があります）
他に落ちそうな部分としては、ご提示いただいたコード中にはありませんがonPause()等の途中の処理は問題ないでしょうか。

キャッシュが悪さをしている可能性もあるため、一度、File→Invalidate/Caches Resartを実行してみても良いかもしれません。（開発環境はAndroidStudioを想定しています）